# How do I move panes in iTerm2 when the pane title bar is disabled?

Tags: iterm2

I find pane title bars visually unnecessary. But they seem to be the only way to move panes around?

Is there another way to move them? I'd rather have them disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I move panes in iTerm2

> Move a pane with the mouse <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then drag the pane from anywhere

Source: [An iTerm2 Cheatsheet · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/squarism/ae3613daf5c01a98ba3a)

Comment: This is perfect. Is this in the app menu items anywhere? I haven't found it, and I'd like to know where to look when I forget this sequence (which I will)

Comment: Look in the cheat sheet I linked :)

Comment: Yes I checked it out, thanks. But my question is if that keyboard shortcuts on the cheatsheet can also be found in the iTerm2 menu or app (I can't find them). I'd prefer not to track a second information source indefinitely if the info can be found somehow through iTerm2 itself.

Comment: No idea - I don't use iTerm